# How to make unique id creating form like gmail id?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, algolia

I want to give a form through user have to create their own unique id.

My basic plan is using algolia's instant search bar to explore already created relating id list by hits through the user ignores the ids. (poor plan :) ). And if the user submits duplicate id that should not be acceptable.

I am confused, please help me to move proper way.

Comment: Hi, from your question content we can't extract a particular specific issue, could you elaborate on what you are building and if you encountered any issue? Maybe give us some mockups or images and platforms, are you building for the desktop, ios, android?

Comment: For android Application

Comment: Can you precise what you are building as a website, give us more details about the UI you want to build, what did you try until now and if you encountered any issue with Algolia?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We are a question-and-answer site, not a coders-for-hire service. Please explain what you have tried so far and why it hasn't worked.

Comment: I too know. I asking idea.